# Google-cloud-sdk install failing with in invalid syntax

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

/home/sohail//google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sohail//google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 27, in 
    from googlecloudsdk import gcloud_main
  File "/home/sohail//google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud_main.py", line 37, in 
    from googlecloudsdk.command_lib.util.apis import yaml_command_translator
  File "/home/sohail//google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/util/apis/yaml_command_translator.py", line 241
    if self.spec.async:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Script execution failed!
Exiting with status 1.

Comment: Where are you installing this  ?

Comment: installing it on ubuntu inside virtualbox

Comment: What command are you using to install the Cloud SDK? What version of Python is installed?

Comment: I would also suspect a python version mismatch. The SDK requires Python 2.7.x

Comment: @AdiDembak apologize for the late reply. Yes you are correct. For google-cloud-sdk python2.7 minimum is required otherwise installation will fail.